# How do I made my road more curvy?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine

https://zapodaj.net/4478fa0baa9c4.png.html

I used curve and array, but my road is not smooth (subdivide doesnt work)

Comment: Hello please share your object: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Turn up the curve resolution

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simple, **your road is too low poly**, I assume it's just made of one plane with 4 vertices and subdividing the curves won't solve that :

[image]

Try to go to **edit mode** and **subdivide** your road mesh **perpendicularly to the direction of the curve** like so :

[image]

And you will get the desired result :

[image]

The more subdivisions you add the smoother it will be. Don't overdo it though.

Hope I helped.